# rails 3 mass assignment error, simple yet unresolvable

Tags: ruby-on-rails, forms, ruby-on-rails-3.2, mass-assignment

I have been trying to figure out why I keep receiving mass-assignment errors when my code seems to be correct. Am I using the wrong syntax? I would really appreciate any beta, I have been trying to debug such a simple part of my application and its really halting my progress. I have the following:

## controller

```
class ProductsController < ApplicationController
def new
        @product =Product.new
end

def create
        @product = Product.new(params[:product])
end

end
```

## models

```
class Product < ActiveRecord::Base
  attr_accessible :name, :colors_attributes
  has_many :colors
  accepts_nested_attributes_for :colors, allow_destroy: true
end

class Color < ActiveRecord::Base
        attr_accessible :name, :product_id
        belongs_to :product
end
```

## Migrations

```
class CreateProducts < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :products do |t|
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end

class CreateColors < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :colors do |t|
      t.integer :product_id
      t.string :name

      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

## Views

products/new.html.erb

```
 <%= render "form" %>
```

products/_form.html.erb

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
        <%= f.text_field :name %>
        <%= f.fields_for :color do |c| %>
                <%= render 'color_fields', f: c %>
        <% end %>
        <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

products/_color_fields.html.erb

```
<%= f.text_field :name %>
```

Error:

```
ActiveModel::MassAssignmentSecurity::Error in ProductsController#create

Can't mass-assign protected attributes: color
```

Full trace:

```
activemodel (3.2.3) lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:48:in `process_removed_attributes'
activemodel (3.2.3) lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:20:in `debug_protected_attribute_removal'
activemodel (3.2.3) lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security/sanitizer.rb:12:in `sanitize'
activemodel (3.2.3) lib/active_model/mass_assignment_security.rb:230:in `sanitize_for_mass_assignment'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/attribute_assignment.rb:75:in `assign_attributes'
activerecord (3.2.3) lib/active_record/base.rb:498:in `initialize'
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:7:in `new'
app/controllers/products_controller.rb:7:in `create'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/action_controller/metal/implicit_render.rb:4:in `send_action'
actionpack (3.2.3) lib/abstract_controller/base.rb:167:in `process_action'
...
```

any insight would be appreciated

Comment: what is the error your getting.

Comment: I appended the error and a full trace to the bottom of the post

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this is what you want

```
<%= form_for @product do |f| %>
  <%= f.text_field :name %>
  <%= f.fields_for :colors do |c| %>
    <%= render 'color_fields', f: c %>
  <% end %>
  <%= f.button :submit %>
<% end %>
```

Your `fields_for` was using `:color` instead of `:colors`

Comment: You may also want to check out this [railscast](http://railscasts.com/episodes/196-nested-model-form-part-1)

Comment: I've followed that railcast and everything in my code is correct. I changed :colors to :color because when its :colors (your suggestion) the color_fields partial is not rendered. This leaves me with just the product form and no color fields. (no error is generated)

Comment: In your controller in the new action do a `@product.colors.build`